# Finding a metric space where singletons are closed and open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am asked to find a metric space where singletons are closed and open(such a space is totally disconnected).

I was thinking of the metric space $(M,d)$ where $d$ is the discrete metric.  Does this work?  Thanks!!

Comment: Singletons are closed in every metric space, so you don't have to worry about it. You only need to find a metric where singletons are open. Your example is fine, but you need to show these of course.

Comment: How would I show that a singleton is open, using the discrete metric.  I know that singletons are trivially closed for every metric space.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your idea is absolutely correct.

In a discrete space $X$ every subset of $X$ is open.

So if $\{x\}$ is a singleton in a discrete space $X$ then it is open.

Also $X \setminus \{x\}$ is open thus its complement which is $\{x\}$ is closed.

Thus every singleton is open and closed in a discrete space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works.

For the discrete metric, 
$$
d(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\;\;x=y\\[4pt]
1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
singletons are open, since each singleton $\{x\}$ is equal to the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $x$.

But if singletons are open, then every subset of $M$ is open, since every subset of $M$ is a union of singletons.

Since every subset of $M$ is open, it follows that the every subset of $M$ is also closed (since its complement is open).

Hence all subsets of $M$ are both open and closed.